# Domain of the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt {x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1}}$

Tags: functions

What is the domain of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt {x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1}}$$ the answer is $(-\infty,\infty)$. Now the polynomial has degree $12$. Also it's continuously increasing from $1$. So I thought there might be a value in negative side which may create $0$ thus making function undefined. How can one prove or be sure that polynomial has only complex roots. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

$$x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1=x^9(x^3-1)+x(x^3-1)+1=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x^8+1)+1$$

We can see that this is positive for $x\ge 1$ or $x\le 0$.

For $0\lt x\lt 1$, 
$$x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1=x^{12}+(1-x)+x^4(1-x^5)$$
is positive since $1-x^5\gt 0$.

Therefore, $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1$ is positive.

Answer (score 3):

Take the function $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x=x(x^3-1)(x^8+1)$ This has 2 real roots at $0$ and at $1$ and increases on both sides . So the minima is in between them. Find out the minima and check the function's value, ..it will come out to be $>-1$. So adding $+1$ to the entire function pushes up the lowest point above the $X$ axis ,resulting in no real roots..

Answer (score 0):

It is eay to see that $f(-x)$ has no sign changes in its terms thereby giving no negative real roots but $f(x)$ has atmost four positive real roots (Descarte's rule). See, that it also has no rational roots as $1$ and $-1$ were the only possible candidates. Hence , there may be either two or four irrational roots(Why?). Now, we claim that if $p$ and $q$ are its only two irrational roots then

$pq=1$ and $p+q$=0 (Why?)

As the above two conditions give no real values of $p$ and $q$, our claim is wrong.
  A similar argument may be given for second case.